# X11 Forwarding over SSH to use xterm

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I am trying to connect from an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (source) to another Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (destination) to use xterm (in destination). When trying to connect, i do `ssh -X ubuntu@destination`, and when i run xterm on destination, after setting the DISPLAY variable with `export DISPLAY=ip-destination:11.0` i get the following error message: `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: ip-destination:11.0`
I´ve checked my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and have this:
UsePAM yes

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
##GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
#PermitTTY yes
XauthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

Among the rest of the file.

I have already install `xauth` and `xterm`, and have `.Xauthority` file in `/home/ubuntu` with 600 permissions.

When debugging with: `ssh -X -v ubuntu@destination` i get:

```
debug1: Remote: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding

debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
```

Also, when running: `netstat -at`, i get the following:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6012            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Any ideas of why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you copy&paste the full error message? Maybe you have to set the `DISPLAY` variable.

Comment: Hi @Bodo, i have set the display variable indeed (i already edited that in the question). Even after setting the variable, i get the error.

Comment: Adding to my previouis comment: Is there nothing after `... Can't open display:`? I would expect the display specification after the colon. What is `ip` in `export DISPLAY=ip:11.0`? Are you sure `11` is the right display number? I suggest to show your sequence of commands with their output in a code block.

Comment: Yes, i just edited the question with the full error message. ip paramater means the ip of the destination server. About the display number, i assume it is, since i have X11DisplayOffset 10 in the source server.

Comment: Please add all information to your question instead of using comments to answer. When you run an X program on `destination-ip` you don't need `destination-ip` in the `DISPLAY` variable. You can use `DISPLAY=:11.0` or `DISPLAY=localhost:11.0` (assuming the `11.0` part is correct). Does `netstat -at` on *destination* show any port numbers around 6000? Show these output lines.

Comment: I will keep that part in mind. About netstat -at, i am getting at 0.0.0.0 ports 6010, 6011, 6012

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139190/discussion-between-nano-dorado-and-bodo).

Comment: **Please add all requested information to the question** instead of answering in comments. To avoid mistakes or misunderstanding, copy&paste the command and the *complete output lines* to your question as a code block. The port numbers should correspond to display 10, 11 and 12, so you could try `DISPLAY=:10` or `DISPLAY=localhost:10`, or 11 or 12. Without the full output I don't know if all these ports are still listening for connections. Maybe only display 12 is active and the ports for 10 and 11 are in a TIME_WAIT state.

Comment: Run `ssh -X -v ubuntu@destination` and check for error messages related to X11 forwarding.

Comment: I get these two lines:
`debug1: Remote: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding`
`debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output

```
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
```

you should set the `DISPLAY` variable on the *source* system before running `ssh`. The `DISPLAY` variable on the *destination* system will probably get set by `ssh` when the forwarding is successful.

Comment: Thank you @Bodo! This solved the issue. :)

Comment: @nano_dorado Then you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark. If this is not yet possible you might have to wait some time.